# PHP OO Cancel Construction

Tags: php, oop, caching, constructor

This is actually an interesting question, and there's an easy (but ugly) fix to it (see below).

So I'm asking if there's a better way to do it.

What I'd like to do is making an object constructor return something else rather than a new instance.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$GLOBALS['object_cache']=array();

class Test {
    public function __construct($id=0){
        if(isset( $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id] ))
            return $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id];
        $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id]=$this;
    }
}

$t0=new Test(0);
$t1=new Test(1);
$t01=new Test(0);
// modifying $t01 would presumably also modify $t0
```

The easy (but ugly?) fix:

```
$GLOBALS['object_cache']=array();

class Test {
    public static function create($id=0){
        if(isset( $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id] ))
            return $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id];
        $new=new Test();
        $GLOBALS['object_cache'][$id]=$new;
        return $new;
    }
}

$t0=Test::create(0);
$t1=Test::create(1);
$t01=Test::create(0);
// modifying $t01 would presumably also modify $t0
```

What do you guys think? Example 1 doesn't work, by the way; it returns a new instance regardless of the return statement.

So am I missing something, or is the better way the second one?

PS: No need stating the obvious about patterns (factory/singleton)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a procedural version:

```
class Test {
    function __construct($i) {}
}
function Test($i) {
    static $cache;
    if (isset($cache[$i])) {
        return $cache[$i];
    }
    else { 
        return $cache[$i] = new Test($i);
    }
}
```

It's slightly nicer on the eyes, and allows for e.g. instant fluent `Test(1)->do()->else()` calls.

Comment: Although I thought about it before, it seems to me it's the best way so far. Oh and thanks for getting to the point...

Answer (score 4):

1. Omg. Constructor cannot return anything.
2. It is called factory method pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern and it is a common practice to instantiate objects.

ps: Store the instances in `static` class variable and second solution will not be so weird like now.

Comment: 1. That depends on the language. For the matter, it does return something; the new instance.  2. I know about that, but I focused on coding since the problem is in my code not theoretical design patterns.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: to be clear - it returns, yes, but you are not able to write `return` explicitly. I wonder if any programming language allows it.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: 2. well, you have no choice ;-) You have to choose good and academical solution that even **works** ;-)

Comment: zerkms - what I was asking is, is there any better way? As Emil said, the academical answer isn't as obvious... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#PHP  I noticed that they specifically disabled the constructor...though a good idea in their case, I'd rather use a cleaner approach.

Comment: @Christian 1. It happens to return a new instance, but not because you're `returning` it from the constructor. The new instance is returned because you're using the `new` keyword to invoke the constructor.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: design patterns is a common way to interact between developers. If someone doesn't understand them - fire or teach him.

Comment: @deceze - No need to state the obvious...the constructor doesn't usually need to return anything, so think of it as a feature. What if object construction fails? One could use this feature to return false or raise an exception. If the feature isn't supported, it doesn't make the whole idea wrong.

Comment: @zerkms - Design patterns often lead to a lot of confusing and unmaintainable code. A clear example? MVC in Joomla.  Just look at all those demos in that wiki article, there isn't even two of them which match in their coding, yet they are programmed in OOP languages!

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: **LOL**. Joomla in a discussion about OOAD and design patterns. I never even imagine I see that )))))

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: "One could use this feature to return false" --- have you ever tried to get the "false" returned by constructor actually? "it doesn't make the whole idea wrong" --- actually, it does. The constructor is obliged to "return" the data of specific type. You are not allowed to return boolean.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: I did not get the point. The Joomla has terrible code. Joomla's code has nothing to do with design patterns just their names. If you want an example - look at zend at least then.

Comment: @zerkms - 1. I already stated the feature is non-existent. 2. No the idea is not wrong. There is no such obligation except your assumption. If 30 languages adopted the same set of OO features doesn't mean they can't get to another one. 3. The point is, thanks to the big hack (such as my second example) one first has to identify the design pattern (singleton+factory) and then figure out what the heck I'm doing. Design pattern or not, the coder sees code, ugly one in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're trying to do is implementing a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) combined with a [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Anyone should be able to tell how it works if you document it in your technical documentation (and in your comments), so the first way can be used.

The second solution actually seems *less* obvious to me.

Comment: second (the factory method) is not enough obvious?! O_o. First can be used?!?!? How? ;-)

Comment: Hi there. That is spot-on; the problem with the first is that it doesn't work.

Comment: @zerkms - It is not obvious in the sense that you are *constructing* instances with a *static method*.